# Magento adding custom fields / tabs

Tags: php, magento, field, sections

I was following this tutorial to add custom fields : 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/admin/xml_structure_for_admin_configurations

But I am unable to see new fields/tabs/sections in the configuration.
Something to do with cache? Compiling? Index Managment?

Thanx in advance

Comment: logout and log in again.

Comment: Didn't work. Strange...

Comment: Got it! I didn't activate my module